# PHP сравнение промежутка времени и вывод минут

Tags: php, laravel, время

Как в Laravel сравнить промежуток времени между полями 'created_at' и 'updated_at'?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько мне известно можно функцией time() вычислить разницу, а далее определять кратность того, что вам нужно.
Если считать не охота можно применить.

```
print date("H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, difftime()));
$diffdate =date("H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, difftime()));
```

А далее  передать её:

```
return view('pages.blog')->with([
  'diffdate' => $diffdate
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel использует `Carbon` для своих дат, у этого объекта есть метод `diff` который выведет разницу между датами в виде объекта `DateInterval`, или есть более детальные методы `diffInDays`, `diffInHours`, `diffInMinutes` и т.д.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$diff = $user->updated_at->diffInMinutes($user->created_at);
```

Вывод будет кол-во минут разницы между датами, если хотите свой формат используйте метод `diff`.

Comment: "Laravel использует Carbon для своих дат" - Неверно. Без дополнительных настроек он возвращает даты в формате MySQL.

Comment: @Mrak почему же? Я сказал - для своих дат, свои даты это `created_at`, `updated_at`, на них сразу мутаторы подключены по умолчанию

Comment: Теперь понятно.

Comment: Может у меня Laravel старый (5.3), но сейчас проверил - и возвращается обычная строка в формате Mysql

Comment: @Mrak с 4 версии такое было, возможно в модели переназначены даты или выключены вообще, поставьте чистый Laravel из коробки и увидите это, полез сейчас в саму доку и вот там есть такая строчка - By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at and updated_at columns to instances of Carbon, то что я и говорил

Comment: @Mark это он их при выводе так изображает, а так там на само деле [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) можешь даже проверить подставив метод ```$user->update_at->diffInHours($user->created_at)```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo floor((strtotime($x->updated_at) - strtotime($x->created_at)) / 60);
```